# Can I add MFC support to an Existing ATL COM project

Tags: c++, windows, com, mfc, atl

I have created a Shell Extension using ATL COM Object . But during creation I haven't added MFC support. Can I change the setting now to add MFC support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but I believe that doing this won't auto-add all the required headers and #defines - of course, you could try this first, and check to be sure.

If that does not work, you could use 'File->New->Project from Existing Code' to create a new project in your solution that uses both MFC and ATL, using the code in your original project.  You would have to include any custom settings from your current ATL-only version, but if you let a new precompiled header be created in the new project, it should have all the MFC and ATL bits you need turned on and included.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a [knowledge base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173974) article that says how to do this.  In short, you basically have to add certain `#include`s and create an application object, along with some plumbing.