# using mfc class library inside ATL project

Tags: visual-c++, atl

I have created IE Toolbar using ATL projects, I want to do manipulation with the page that will loaded in browser through my toolbar.

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add what 'manipulation' you would like to do. And what is the correlation between MFC and this need?

Comment: @gammay I want to manipulate page content for e.g. hide the images from the page & hide the unnecessary adds from the page etc. plz anybody guid me how to use mfc in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually add MFC headers into your code, see:

- [MFC Support in ATL Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490ke8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Can I add MFC support to an Existing ATL COM project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932487/can-i-add-mfc-support-to-an-existing-atl-com-project)
- [How to add MFC support to an ATL project in Visual C++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173974)

Comment: plz can any one tell me how to add mfc support in my atl project ?