# How to add Classes that use MFC to an ATL project?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, atl

I'm writing a .NET profiler (a DLL) and I'm using ATL. I'd like to add some classes that use MFC to my project but I got many errors however those classes work fine with an MFC project. I tried to change project properties and set `Use of MFC = Use MFC in a shared DLL` but it didn't work, I tried also including "afx.h"...

Here are some of the errors I got :

```
Error   214 error C2373: 'CString' : redefinition; different type modifiers iaparameters.cpp    31

Error   206 error C2653: 'CIAParameters' : is not a class or namespace name iaparameters.cpp    30
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which ATL/MFC Version are you using? With VS2010/2012 you should be able to add MFC support to your ATL project (right click to the project, add, new item, MFC support). Also the redefinition of CString seems like an version missmatch to me, since CString is an shared class of ATL and MFC since ATL 8.

Answer (score 0):

Baislcy this should be possible, regarding to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932487/can-i-add-mfc-support-to-an-existing-atl-com-project). But from my own experience it is a little bit tricky to do this. You have to manually include the MFC headers for the version you are using. Also you might customize your `CWinApp` class to enable MFC class factories ([this is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490ke8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) what default MFC support generates for you. Also [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173974/en) might help).

Also you should note that with ATL 8 the most important classes of MFC & ATL are now [shared between both libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzs00fs6.aspx).

If this does not work the easiest way is to recreate the project, checking the *MFC support* option and reimport your code. This is how I ended up doing this.

Last but not least you should also note that [ATL Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321159624) states that you should only use MFC when you really have to. Almost all powerfull MFC helpers are also part of ATL, nowdays. Here's a quote from the book. The two first reasons are a big plus for ATL, the last one is more like a joke:

> 1. **I can't live without `CString` (or `CMap`, `CList`, and so on)** The MFC utility classes were built as a stopgap until the C++ standards committee defined a standard library. They've done it, so we can stop using the MFC versions. The classes `string`, `map`, `list`, and so on provided in the standard library are more flexible and more robust than their MFC equivalents. Moreover, `CString` is now a shared class between MFC and ATL, and thus is available in ATL projects without having to include the rest of MFC and link to the MFC library. Other MFC utility classes have also been made shared, including `CPoint` and `CRect`. And for those who liked the MFC collections classes, ATL now includes MFC style collections (`CAtlMap`, `CAtlList`, and so on).
> 2. **I can't live without the wizards.** [...] The ATL wizards are arguably as extensive as the ones MFC provides.
> 3. **I already know MFC, and I can't learn anything new.** [...]

ATL provides good support for STL containers and types. You should consider using them, instead of referencing MFC.